# Most frequent pattern with an order

Tags: java, apriori

i'm searching for an algorithm like Apriori but with order.

I need an algorithm to find most frequent pattern.
Example:
A B C D E
A B C
A C B D
D E C F

the most frequent pattern: A B C

The order is very important. A C B should not be viewed because A C B is only one times in my example, but A B C three times.

Is there an algorithm or is the best solution to code it by my own?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can use a trie data structure to easily code it up. its complexity is less too

Comment: the pattern you are looking for has to be a triplet, right?

Comment: Regex should be a good start !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scan the sequence and store populations in a `map`

```
String sequence = "ABCDEABCACBDDECF";

char[] chars = sequence.toCharArray();
int i = 0;
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
while(i < chars.length - 2){
    String pattern = "" + chars[i] + chars[i+1] + chars[i+2];
    System.out.println(pattern);
    Integer population = map.get(pattern);
    if(population == null){
        population = 1;
    }else{
        population++;
    }
    map.put(pattern, population);

    i++;
}

System.out.println(map);
```

The output is

```
{ACB=1, DEA=1, BCA=1, ABC=2, BCD=1, BDD=1, DEC=1, CAC=1, CBD=1, DDE=1, CDE=1, EAB=1, ECF=1}
```

You can easily sort the map by values : http://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/java-sort-map-by-value/ or just scan the map looking for the highest population

By the way: population of pattern `ABC` actually is 2 not 3

Comment: ok, thank you, I think that I can use this. I have no chars but strings. Thats no problem. The algorithm works fine.